# Rails validations on create and update methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, validation

So i have the following scenario. I want to create a new User but i want it's email to be unique. So i have the following validation

```
  def uniq_email
    errors.add(:email, "Already existing User with email: #{email}") if
      User.exists?(email: email)
  end
```

This works good. The problem is when i want to update this user, if i try to change the email with an already existing one it allows me to do that.
I tried adding [:create, :update] in validation but if i do this, when i change it's address for example it runs again the validation on the model and tells me that user with that email already exists.
Any help? How can i avoid this?

Thank you :D

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for your scenario is to use [validates_uniqueness_of](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of) or [uniqueness](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) as it ensures the email uniqueness at the application level.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  # or
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
end
```

To make the uniqueness bulletproof, a unique index on email should be added in the db. If, for some reason, you bypass the validations in the model, the DB will raise an error.

```
class MakeEmailUnique < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true
  end
end
```

You should go over the [Validation Docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) docs to learn more about how to use them.

Comment: This is correct, as far as validations are concerned. I only wanted to add that one should also add a unique index on email in the database, for actual protection. This validation is useful for getting error messages, but it doesn't _guarantee_ uniqueness.

Comment: Yes of course, this should be doubled by a uniqueness constraint. Will update.